# PHP: Appending to File with Paginated API Call - Data Overwrites and Does not Append

Tags: php, pagination, php-curl

I am calling a paginated API that has a standard return of 100 records per page and uses a cursor to advance to the next page. The JSON returned has a pageInfo object that contains the total number of records, cursor, and hasMore elements. I run a while loop and move the cursor to the next page to get the data until hasMore is false.

For some reason, the file only contains the last page from the set even though I am opening it and writing with the append notation. I think I might be doing something wrong in the loop.

Interestingly, though not noted in the code shared here, I have successfully created an incitement variable for the filename (i.e. filename$x) instead of appending it to the existing file, and it works fine in the loop. I get 6 discreet files with 100 records in the first 5 and 20 in the last one, but that is not what I want.

For this code, I am showing what I want to happen, which is to append to the existing file, but instead, I just get the last page of records in the file. Please forgive the ugly and poorly indented nature of this code, though I commented it.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time','240');
$url = "https://myDomain/incoming/v2/content";

  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  
  $headers = array(
     "Accept: application/json",
     "Authorization: Bearer myKey",
  );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  //for debug with localhost only!
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Execute the curl request 
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Check for errors
if ($response === false) { die("Error: " . curl_error($curl)); }

// Decode the JSON response and write inital data to file
file_put_contents('CURL-MEETINGS-ILT-VILT_NEWEST.txt', $response);

//dump some data to screen for teesting
$data = json_decode($response, true);
$pageinfo=$data['pageInfo'];
$hasmore=$data['pageInfo'] ['hasMore'];
print "THIS IS THE pageinfo"; var_dump($pageinfo);
print "THIS IS THE hasmore"; var_dump($hasmore);
var_dump($response);

 // Loop through all pages and write to file
 while ($data['pageInfo'] ['hasMore'] === true) {

    // Get the cursor for the current page
      $cursor = $data['pageInfo']['cursor'];

    //set the cursor to the new page 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://myDomain/incoming/v2/content?cursor=$cursor");
     
    // Execute the curl request
     $response1 = curl_exec($curl);
     
    //dump cursor to the screen for testing
      print "THIS IS THE cursor1"; var_dump($cursor);
        if ($response1 === false) { die("Error: " . curl_error($curl)); }
        
    //write to file
    $fp = fopen('CURL-MEETINGS-ILT-VILT_NEWEST.txt', 'a');//opens file in append mode  
    fwrite($fp, $response1);  
    fclose($fp);   
    echo "File appended successfully";  

    //Close the curl handle
     curl_close($curl);
}

?>
```

Comment: FYI you can use the `FILE_APPEND` flag with `file_put_contents()` to append.

Comment: Make sure you're adding a newline at the end of the file each time you write to it. Otherwise everything will be on the same line.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't add that I  have tried both file_put_contents() with the flag and fopen(). Same results for both.  As for newline, the JSON string is fine in the file.

Comment: How are you trying to read the file? `json_decode()` can only handle one JSON, you shouldn't have multiple JSON strings in the file. You should combine everything into one JSON object.

Comment: You're correctly using `a` mode when opening the file, so I can't see any reason why you're only getting the last page.

Comment: I am somewhat new to using the paginated call with a cursor.  I am using json_decode() to handle the string  as an array so that I can check that the hasMore===true and also to dump some elements to the screen to see that things are coming in as expected.  When the HasMore element===false, then there are no more pages.

The weird thing is that if I add an option to write each page returned to a file (incrementing the filename with each loop), I get the 6 discreet files with 100 records in the first 5 and 20 in the sixth one.  But  I only get the last 20 in the appended file.

Comment: @Barmar I think I figured it out. I was looking at my viewer in Notepad++ that shows the last page of records, when in fact they are all there. When I loop through the pages, I am getting the **pageInfo** object and all the **contentItems** array of objects sent each time. While they append, the JSON viewer has a hard time because I have 6 instances of the pageInfo object  and 6 instances of the contentItems in the file.  But all the data from all 6 pages is there.

Comment: I guess that I need to determine the best way to have one instance of contentItems that contains one full array for all 6 pages, not starting over with a new array [0]-[99] inside of 6 contentItems arrays, but I am not sure how to do that given that I have to move the cursor each time.

Comment: Use `json_decode()` to parse each page. Concatenate all the arrays into one big array. At the end of the loop, call `json_encode()` to convert that to JSON, and write it all to the file.